# Can't install new Program after update Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, networking, package-management, updates

Today, I lost my network manager after an update but brought it back with

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

But now, I can't install new programs. running sudo apt-get install program_name retuns

```
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
libnl-3-200 : Breaks: libnl-3-200:i386 (!= 3.2.21-1) but 3.2.21-1ubuntu1 is to be installed
libnl-3-200:i386 : Breaks: libnl-3-200 (!= 3.2.21-1ubuntu1) but 3.2.21-1 is to be installed
libnl-genl-3-200 : Depends: libnl-3-200 (= 3.2.21-1ubuntu1) but 3.2.21-1 is to be installed
libnl-route-3-200 : Depends: libnl-3-200 (= 3.2.21-1ubuntu1) but 3.2.21-1 is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Running sudo apt-get -f install then return:

```
Preparing to unpack .../libnl-3-200_3.2.21-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libnl-3-200:amd64 (3.2.21-1ubuntu1) over (3.2.21-1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libnl-3-200_3.2.21-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
trying to overwrite shared '/usr/share/doc/libnl-3-200/changelog.Debian.gz', which is different from other instances of package libnl-3-200:amd64
Errors were encountered while processing:
/var/cache/apt/archives/libnl-3-200_3.2.21-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

My /var/cache/apt/archives/ has two *.deb files and a lock file along with a folder named partial. How do I sort out above problem. Most importantly I need to install some programs. Please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got it working by deleting both the *.deb files in /var/cache/apt/archives/  . But I don't know why it happened.

Comment: I got mine to stop throwing errors by going into `cd /usr/share/doc` and deleting the libnl folders with `sudo rm -r libnl*-3-200`. Then opened the software updater app which worked again